# Thumbnail Content Management System (CMS)?

Tags: web, content-management-system

Hi I am looking for a CMS, that would allow me to add/view items based on categories. Just like a shopping cart but much simpler than that. I am working on a project which requires to categorize Movies based on their genre. So, there will be categories like Action, Romance,etc. Under each category, I need to display an image/video and some text regarding the movie. Which CMS would allow me do this?. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `Joomla` for your requirement. Joomla have lot of components and modules for your requirments.

Better you go with Joomla.. :)

This Joomla plugin has all privileges to fulfill your requirement.

[Click here](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/authoring-a-content/content-construction/8061)

Answer (score 0):

Our company already has a CMS that facilitates this. One of clients is an video/games and entertainment company with an online e-commerce site.

You can contact us via our website www.monadel.com.

However, we are B2B and you may be looking for freeware - which we are not currently offering.

Wishing you success in your endeavours.